# pointwise convergent sequence of bounded variation functions

Tags: functions, bounded-variation, pointwise-convergence

Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of functions. Given:

1. $f_k$ is a bounded variation function on $[a,b]$ for any $k$
2. sequence $f_k$ converges to $f$ point-wise.

Question: is $f$ necessarily a bounded variation function on $[a,b]$?

Comment: $f$ need not even  be bounded, so it need not be of bounded variation.

Comment: Kabo, please a concrete counter-example. I’ll accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=0,b=1$, $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n(x)=\frac 1 x$ for $x > \frac  1 n$, $n$ for $0<x \leq \frac 1 n$. Let $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x=0$. Then $f$ is not even bounded so it is not of bounded variation. Each $f_n$ is of bounded variation because it is decresing and bounded on $(0,1]$.